# Definition of complex vector space from Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces

[image]

This is definition of complex vector space from Rudin's book. He write that to each pair $(\alpha,x)$, where $x\in V$ and $\alpha$ is scalar there is associated a vector $\alpha x\in V$. That's right. But what about $x+y$? Is it also an element of $V$? Rudin didn't say about this nothing.

Comment: Does the second question bear any relation to the first? I would consider asking it separately.

Comment: @Micapps, They have no relation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "there corresponds a vector $x+y$" imply that $x+y\in V$, since a vector (according to the previous paragraph) is simply an element of $V$.

Comment: Note that in the case $\alpha x$ he also write that it's a vector but he emphasized that it's from $V$